# Use Row and Column header to determine combinations in Excel

Tags: excel

My data consist of a matrix of `1` and `0` that denote a connection.

I need to get all combinations of connections as a list. Sample data looks like this

```
      Head Foot Hand
Head    0    1    0
Foot    1    0    0
Hand    0    0    1
```

So there is a connection between head & foot, foot & head and hand & hand.

So I need an output that simply states these connections as a list:

```
Head, Foot
Foot, Head
Hand, Hand
```

Comment: This question is not clear.

Comment: I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Look into pivot tables.  I have given you a "core" Excel solution in my answer below which _may_ suffice for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a matrix below your input data according to this sample:

[image]

The cell `C6` has this formula:

```
=IF(C2 = 1, CONCATENATE($A2, ", ", C$1), "")
```

You can simply copy this result matrix to a text editor to obtain a list.  If you want a solution entirely in Excel, you should look into Pivot Tables.

Comment: Thank you Tim. This does exactly what I wanted.

Comment: One additional comment: If you want to avoid duplicates (e.g. `Head, Foot` is the same as `Foot, Head`), then you can simply fill in only the lower diagonal of the matrix.